# Table View Cell Height randomly not calculating some Cell Heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, sdwebimage

I have a *few* Table View Cell Heights randomly not calculating some Cell Heights by the time they are on screen.

[image]

***(Scrolling down)***

[image]

**Only when they go off screen, and then scrolled back up to, do they calculate as needed.

***(Scrolling Back up)***

Has anyone ever heard of this, or know what to do?

*I'm using AutoLayout, Storyboards, SDWebImage to load the images from a URL, and this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:*

```
 __weak TableViewCellTwo *wcell = api2Cell;
[wcell.imageViewPic
    sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff.png"]
    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fff.png"]
    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
// Put Log
        }
 ];
```

My Storyboard:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Wanted to add to my question to see if I could get an answer.  Still having problems with this.  Wondering if there's any way to do this without using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.  Is this just an iOS bug?

Comment: I think it because you set the imageview's image Asynchronously.So when tableview layout, the image is nil, so the cell height is wrong.

Comment: @mengxiangjian so that would end up affecting just a couple of the cells but not all of them?  Just wondering.  And per your recommendation, how would you do what I'm trying to do?  Thanks!

Comment: tell me something, does cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called first, or the heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty I didn't put a `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because I'm using Storyboards and AutoLayout, do I still need one?  Thanks!

Comment: I follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout, for cellViews with dynamic height

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty yeah I've checked that out, but it didn't necessarily account for new iOS 8 features with not necessarily needing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` anymore.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you set the cell height programatically, and you are using auto resize/ autoLayout.

Comment: @VineeshTP  I'm using AutoLayout

Comment: Do you set the cell height programatically, ?

Comment: No I use the Storyboard to set the cell height